# Decltype on static variable in template class

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

I'm trying to define a static variable of a templated class outside of the class scope using clang:

```cpp
class Bar
{
public:
    float a;
};

template<long count>
class Foo {
public:
    static Bar* test;
};

template<long count>
decltype(Foo<count>::test) Foo<count>::test; // error

int main() {
    Foo<5> f;
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following error:
`error: redefinition of 'test' with a different type: 'decltype(Foo<count>::test)' vs 'Bar *'`

It looks to me like `decltype(Foo<count>::test)` should evaluate to `Bar *`.

This code works fine on MSVC.

My question: Is there anyway to get `decltype` to correctly determine the type here?

In the actual code, `decltype` is defined in a macro that has some additional keywords depending on the configuration used, so I would like to get this working while still using `decltype`.

Comment: Why can't you say `Bar *` as the type instead of `decltype(Foo<count>::test)` in the definition of the static variable `test`?

Comment: MSVC generally has many extensions to accommodate non-standard forms of code that are not otherwise portable.

Comment: The actual code is quite complex, and we'd preferably like to keep the code as close to original as possible. If this is indeed something that's just not possible with clang though, we might have to look at alternatives (`typeof` works just fine for example)

Comment: Notice than msvc also complain in C++20 mode [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1jWaM11z3): *"C2040: 'Foo<count>::test': 'unknown-type' differs in levels of indirection from 'Bar *'"*

Comment: `decltype(Foo<count>::test)` based definition compiles without warning using `g++ -Werror -Wall -Wextra` and it runs as expected.

Comment: Can't you use typedef in `Foo`: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9eMEGvd8v)

Comment: The typedef approach looks good. With the addition of the static assert it should ensure the original code remains unchanged

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<Foo<42>::type, decltype(Foo<42>::test)>);` has better encapsulation and could suit the conditions of your code base better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is ill-formed, because `decltype(Foo<count>::test)` denotes a unique type, even though it is equivalent to `Bar*`.

The relevant standard sections are as follows:

> Two declarations correspond if they (re)introduce the same name, both declare constructors, or both declare destructors, unless [...]

- [basic.scope.scope §4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#4)

We are even shown an example that declarations don't have to be symbolically identical to correspond:

> ```cpp
> typedef int Int;
> /* ... */
> void f(int);                    // #1
> void f(Int) {}                  // defines #1
> ```

- [basic.scope.scope - example 2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#example-2)

However, `decltype` is special in this regard:

> If an expression `e` is [type-dependent](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.expr), `decltype(e)` denotes a unique dependent type.
> Two such *decltype-specifiers* refer to the same type only if their *expressions* are equivalent ([[temp.over.link]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link)).

- [temp.type §4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#4)

In your example:

```cpp
// variable type declared as Bar* elsewhere
template<long count>
decltype(Foo<count>::test) Foo<count>::test;
```

`decltype(Foo<count>::test)` is dependent on `count`, and so the type is unique and different from `Bar*`.
Proving that they are the same for arbitrary expressions is undecidable in the general case, so it makes sense that compilers disallow this.

GCC falsely compiles your example [(see Compiler Explorer)](https://godbolt.org/z/jPr3Kon7T), but clang and MSVC don't.
This is probably because GCC doesn't treat `test` as dependent, since it is declared with type `Bar*`, which is not dependent.
However, that is not conforming.

### Conclusion

Your best course of action is finding a way to define this out-of-line with the same type:

```cpp
template<long count>
Bar* Foo<count>::test;
```

If you can't use `Bar*` directly, maybe there is another way for you to make your use of `decltype` not depend on `count`.

Alternatively, you could also define the `static` member `inline` (since C++17):

```cpp
template<long count>
class Foo {
public:
    static inline Bar* test = ...;
};
```

---

*Note: I've personally run into a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63641505/5740428) with the compiler being unable to match out-of-line definitions of member functions to the declarations in the class.*

Comment: More examples and discussion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294743/dependent-type-or-argument-in-decltype-in-function-definition-fails-to-compile-w

Comment: But is `Foo<count>::test` a dependent name? A qualified name is dependent if its lookup context is dependent and is not the current instantiation ([temp.dep.type]/5.2). But `Foo<count>` is the current instantiation ([temp.dep.type]/1.2). So it would seem that `Foo<count>::test` is not a dependent name here, and the rule about `decltype` doesn't apply.

Comment: @BrianBi `Foo<count>` is not the current instantiation. a *template-id* can only be the current instantiation if it is **in** the definition of a class template. (See [temp.dep.type]§1]). If it was the current instantiation, we would also be allowed to write `Foo` and it would refer to `Foo<count>`.

Comment: @JanSchultke bullet 1.2 says "in the definition of a primary class template **or a member of a primary class template**"

Comment: @BrianBi we're not in the definition of the member *yet*, at least not until we have parsed the name of the declaration `Foo<count>::test`. This is the reason why you can only refer to the current instantation `Foo` directly in member function parameter lists, trailing return types, the initializing expression of data members etc. When specifying the return type of a member function, or the type of a data member, this is not possible, because there is no current instantation.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'd be interested to see the justification for that claim based on normative wording. Note that the *injected-class-name* `Foo` can only be found **by name lookup** once the *declarator-id* has been seen; [basic.scope.class]/1

Comment: @BrianBi I'm starting to think that you're *technically* right, or at least that the standard is under-specified in this regard. However, no compiler implements it this way, in part because it requires arbitrary look-ahead parsing to know that the data member type or member function return type is looked up `Foo<count>` instead of global scope. Not even GCC will compile this code when `Foo<count>::test`'s type depends on `count`, only when it's independent like `Bar*` or `int`.

Comment: @BrianBi the wording is in https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#1. The *locus* of `Foo<count>::test` is only after the declarator, so its type in the declaration specifier sequence is not yet part of the definition.

Comment: @JanSchultke The locus of a definition is not where the definition is considered to begin. It mostly just describes the point where name lookup begins to be able to find the name declared.